# How to speed up copy from Azure Data Lake to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I'm using Azure Data Factory to copy data from Azure Data Lake Store to a collection in Cosmos DB. We will have a few thousand JSON files in data lake and each JSON file is approx. 3 GB. I'm using data factory's copy activity and in the initial run, one file took 3.5 hours to load with the collection set to 10000 RU/s and data factory using default settings. Now I've scaled it up to 50000 RU/s, set cloudDataMovementUnits to 32 and writeBatchSize to 10 to see if it improved the speed, and the same file now takes 2.5 hours to load. Still the time to load thousands of files will take way to long time.

Is there some way to do this in a better way?

Comment: Are you saying that you're attempting to load single documents into Cosmos that are GB in size? The maximum size of a document in Cosmos is 2MB

Comment: No, sorry if I was unclear. Each file contains millions of JSON documents. The JSON documents contain location data and we need to do spatial calculations, which is why we chose Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are inserting "millions" of json documents per 3Gb batch file. Such lack of precision is not helpful when asking this type of question.

Let's run the numbers for 10 million docs per file.

- This indicates 300 bytes per json doc which implies quite a lot of fields per doc to index on each CosmosDb insert.
- If each insert costs 10 RUs then at your budgeted 10,000 RU per sec the doc insert rate would be 1000 x 3600 (seconds per hour) = 3.6 million doc inserts per hour.
- So your observation of 3.5 hours to insert 3 Gb of data representing an assumed 10 million docs is highly consistent with your purchased CosmosDb throughput.

This document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-activity-performance illustrates that the DataLake to CosmosDb Cloud Sink performs poorly compared to other options. I guess the poor performance can be attributed to the default index-everything policy of CosmosDb.

Does your application need everything indexed? Does the CommosDb Cloud Sink utilise less strict eventual consistency when performing bulk inserts?

You ask, is there a better way? The performance table in the linked MS document shows that Data Lake to Polybase Azure Data Warehouse is 20,000 times more performant.

One final thought. Does the increased concurrency of your second test trigger CosmosDb throttling? The MS performance doc warns about monitoring for these events.

Comment: There are 5-10 million documents in each file, so your estimate were quite good. I've tried reducing the amount of indexing, but didn't get any performance improvement, so I don't think Cosmos DB is the bottleneck. We're also using eventual consistency. No, I didn't see any throttling when increasing concurrency.

Comment: @Magnus: An interesting update. You have not mentioned key partitioning though your second test at 50,00 RUs indicates you have declared a partition key. The limited performance gain between 10k and 50k RUs leads me to question how evenly scattered your partition key values are sequenced in your source data files? We can infer from other CosmosDb setup restrictions that 10k RUs is a reasonable maximum query throughput per physical partition and so if your input data is poorly sequenced on partition key you could be maxing out a single physical partition.

Comment: But shouldn't I see some throttling if I was maxing out a single partition? I don't. The partition key I use has 6000 distinct values and the data should be quite evenly distributed over these key values.

Comment: @Magnus: I am not sure, it depends on how sophisticated the throttling back-off signalling is. I thought it just related to hitting the overall provisioned RU cap at a collection level but not I-O saturation on a single physical partition. Your interpretation is equally reasonable. This thread deserves some Microsoft Azure insider contribution because your usage case is exceptional and just the type of scale out challenge that CosmosDb should excel at.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that trying to copy millions of Json files will take time. If it was organized GB of data you could get away with shorter time batch transfers but not with millions of different files.

I don't know if you plan on transferring this type of file from Data Lake often but a good strategy could be to write an application dedicated to do that. Using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB Client Library you can easily create a C# web app that manages your transfers.

This way you can automate those transfers, throttle them, schedule them, etc. You can also host this app on a vm or app service and never really have to think about it.

Comment: We plan to have scheduled, daily loads of this data further on, but I was thinking of using data factory for this. Implementing an application for it seems more complex and would need more maintenance. What is the advantage compared to data factory?

Comment: I would say Data Factory is a great option. Gives similar flexibility to a custom app. But again the main point I'm trying to make is that this is not a completely trivial task you are trying to do and it should be properly designed and thought out.